# Find words containing . in middle or at the end

Tags: python, regex

I need help to find words containing `.` in middle or at the end with regex in python.

Like `N.` or `N.E.` or `North.East` or `N.East.`

Comment: What have you tried? Presumably you don't mean the exact middle. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you specifically *need* to use regex, but here's how you can do it without. Here are a couple of ways of looking at it:

If you're looking anywhere in the word (let's call it `MyString`) *except* the first character, you can use `MyString[1:].contains('.')`, or simply `'.' in MyString[1:]`.

If you want to check the *exact* center of a string, you can use `MyString[len(MyString)/2] == '.'`; if the string has an even number of characters, the righthand character will be checked ('d' in 'abcdef', for instance).

If you want to check the very last character without checking anything else, `MyString[-1] == '.'` is enough.

Assuming that your words are sent as strings, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
/\w+\.\w*\.?/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/iH9bO6/1

Comment: Why could this be what OP is looking for?

Comment: @tripleee, I added the /g because I thought that he is looking several matches on a text. Another aproach? 
Thanks for the feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
^\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.?$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/15